# Why do we pick $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}< \delta$?

Tags: analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous.We set $f_n(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$.Show that $f_n \to f \text{ uniformly }$.

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Since $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous, $\exists \delta>0 $ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

For $y=x+\frac{1}{n}$,we have $|x-x-\frac{1}{n}|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x+\frac{1}{n})|< \epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x+\frac{1}{n})|< \epsilon$

We pick $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}< \delta$

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)| < \epsilon$

and taking the supremun,we get $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} {|f_n(x)-f(x)|} < \epsilon$,so $f_n \to f \text{ uniformly }$.

Could you explain me why we pick  $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}< \delta$ ??

Comment: to achieve that $n\ge n_0$ implies that $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$

Answer (score 3):

Since you need $1/n<\delta$, you must choose any $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n_0<\delta$. As you write, $|x-y|=1/n$, and the choice of $n$ is dictated by the uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: Couldn't I take $\delta=\frac{1}{n_0}$ ? Since $n \geq n_0$,is $\delta=\frac{1}{n_0}$ the maximum value that it can take?

Comment: No: your task is to pick $n_0$! The number $\delta$ is fixed.

Comment: So could I take $n_0=\frac{1}{\delta}$ ?

Comment: Yes and no: $1/\delta$ needn't be a natural number. You should pick the smallest $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ larger than $1/\delta$.

Comment: Aha....I understand.

Comment: So we can take $\frac{1}{n_0} \leq \delta$ ,right?

Answer (score 3):

The part that says "$\frac{1}{n}\lt\delta\Rightarrow...$", is actually saying **if**
"$\frac{1}{n}\lt\delta$" this implies "..."

So to continue with the desired property we must pick an $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}\lt\delta$

It may become more apparent if we look at a real life analogue:

If I pick up an apple, this implies that I can eat it.

Which means I must pick it up to eat it. But I am free to choose when I pick it up and with which hand. This is anologous to the choice of picking an $n_0$.

Comment: ellya! I understand!!! But..how can I formulate the answer at the beginning where I pick $n_0$?? Can I say it like that:

$$\text{We choose } y=x+\frac{1}{n}$$
So,we have: $|x-x-\frac{1}{n}|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x+\frac{1}{n})|< \epsilon \text{ ,that implies } |\frac{1}{n}|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x+\frac{1}{n})|$.

So,$\forall n \geq n_0:$

$$|(x+\frac{1}{n})-x|< \delta \text{ and so we conclude that } |f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)|< \epsilon$$

Or do you have a better idea how I could formulate it?

Answer (score 2):

What does it mean for a sequence $f_n$ to be uniformly convergent to $f$? It just means that for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can choose a $n_0$ so that for all $n\geq n_0$: $sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} {|f_n(x)-f(x)|} < \epsilon$. So what's been done is, that $n_0$ is chosen according to the premise, which is possible hence f is uniformly continous.

Comment: Couldn't we take $\frac{1}{n_0}<\delta$ ?

Comment: Yes, you choose an $n_0$ so that $\frac{1}{n_0}<\delta$

Comment: Could I take instead of $<$, $\leq$ ?So,that it is $\frac{1}{n_0} \leq \delta $ ?

Comment: If you admit $...\leq \delta$ in your formulation of uniform continuity...

Comment: how can I formulate the answer at the beginning where I pick $n_0$?? Can I say it like that:

$$\text{We choose } y=x+\frac{1}{n}$$
So,we have: $|x-x-\frac{1}{n}|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x+\frac{1}{n})|< \epsilon \text{ ,that implies } |\frac{1}{n}|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x+\frac{1}{n})|$.

So,$\forall n \geq n_0:$

$$|(x+\frac{1}{n})-x|< \delta \text{ and so we conclude that } |f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)|< \epsilon$$

Or do you have a better idea how I could formulate it?